# Fast file copy from network PCs to filer

Tags: python

The current method I use runs the python script from a dedicated host machine which loops over the network PCs and transfers the filers to the network filer. Due to this, the host running the python script is maxing out on local disk write reaching 100% intermittently and Ethernet link speed of (~600Mbps/800MBps Tx/Rx speeds - suspecting the disk write limiting from not maxing 1GBPs Eth IO pipe).  Tested on a sample 1TB data which took 6hrs with max file size of 256M. Is it possible to transfer files directly from network PCs to filer without routing the files through host running the script?

The script uses `shutils.copy2()` and concurrent threads for file copy. this is based on suggestion from this [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101616/simple-backup-script-in-python)

looking for some insights on if there is a better faster method to backup folders from multiple network PCs to a filer.

Comment: Instead of having one central host doing the whole work, it might just call a script on the remote hosts, which then move their files directly to filer

Comment: thank you @PabloHenkowski; we reviewed this option but considering the number of host PCs to backup and their individual status as they being in continuous run and other application activities in them, thought this is going to me more overhead in ensuring the script is executed remotely in them (in daemon mode) and maintain. Agree this distributed method will definitely be efficient, but looking for any better options to make a maintenance simple even if its not a central host PC.